How to save large data in xlsx format as getting error while saving it
I want to save data in .xlsx format, but files are getting corrupted. I'm using Spire.Xls, and my .NET Core version is 6.
My code:
using Device_Migration_Admin_Portal.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Spire.Xls;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Device_Migration_Admin_Portal.Controllers
{
    public class ExportController : Controller
    {
        private const int ExcelRowLimit = 1048576; // Maximum rows per Excel sheet
        private readonly DeviceDbContext _dbContext;

        public ExportController(DeviceDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ExportToExcel([FromBody] ExportRequest request)
        {
            try
            {
                var tempFilePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), "DeviceStatus.xlsx");

                Workbook workbook = new Workbook();
                workbook.Worksheets.Clear(); // Remove default worksheets

                int sheetIndex = 0;
                Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add($"Sheet{sheetIndex + 1}");

                DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Device Serial", typeof(string));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Device Name", typeof(string));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Employee ID", typeof(string));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("User Name", typeof(string));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("User Email", typeof(string));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Last Updated Time", typeof(string));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Wave/Ring Number", typeof(string));
                dataTable.Columns.Add("Overall Status", typeof(string));

                // Get all data from request
                var allData = request.FilteredData.Concat(request.PaginatedData).ToList();
                int currentRow = 0;

                // Add headers to the first sheet
                AddHeaders(dataTable);

                foreach (var device in allData)
                {
                    // Create a new sheet if row limit is reached
                    if (currentRow >= ExcelRowLimit)
                    {
                        sheetIndex++;
                        worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add($"Sheet{sheetIndex + 1}");
                        AddHeaders(dataTable); // Add headers to the new sheet
                        currentRow = 0; // Reset row index for the new sheet
                    }

                    var row = dataTable.NewRow();
                    row["Device Serial"] = StripHtmlTags(device.DeviceSerial)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                    row["Device Name"] = StripHtmlTags(device.DeviceName)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                    row["Employee ID"] = StripHtmlTags(device.EmployeeId)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                    row["User Name"] = StripHtmlTags(device.UserName)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                    row["User Email"] = StripHtmlTags(device.UserEmail)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                    row["Last Updated Time"] = StripHtmlTags(device.LastUpdatedTime)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                    row["Wave/Ring Number"] = StripHtmlTags(device.WaveRingNumber)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                    row["Overall Status"] = StripHtmlTags(device.OverallStatus)?.Trim() ?? string.Empty;
                    dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
                    Console.WriteLine(StripHtmlTags(device.DeviceSerial));
                    Console.WriteLine(StripHtmlTags(device.DeviceName));
                    Console.WriteLine(StripHtmlTags(device.EmployeeId));
                    Console.WriteLine(StripHtmlTags(device.UserName));
                    Console.WriteLine(StripHtmlTags(device.LastUpdatedTime));
                    Console.WriteLine(StripHtmlTags(device.WaveRingNumber));
                    Console.WriteLine(StripHtmlTags(device.OverallStatus));
                    currentRow++;

                    // Write the DataTable to the worksheet when the row limit is reached or at the end
                    if (currentRow % ExcelRowLimit == 0 || currentRow == allData.Count)
                    {
                        worksheet.InsertDataTable(dataTable, true, 1, 1, true);
                        dataTable.Clear(); // Clear DataTable for new data
                    }
                }

                // Save to file system
                workbook.SaveToFile(tempFilePath, FileFormat.Version2016);

                // Return the file to the client
                var fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(tempFilePath);
                System.IO.File.Delete(tempFilePath);

                return File(fileBytes, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "DeviceStatus.xlsx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error generating Excel file: {ex.Message}");
                return StatusCode(500, "An error occurred while generating the Excel file.");
            }
        }

        // Utility method to add headers to a DataTable
        private void AddHeaders(DataTable dataTable)
        {
            dataTable.Columns.Clear(); // Clear existing columns
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Device Serial", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Device Name", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Employee ID", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("User Name", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("User Email", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Last Updated Time", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Wave/Ring Number", typeof(string));
            dataTable.Columns.Add("Overall Status", typeof(string));
        }

        // Utility method to strip HTML tags
        private string StripHtmlTags(string input)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
                return input;

            return Regex.Replace(input, "<.*?>", string.Empty);
        }

        // Utility method to escape CSV fields
        private string EscapeCsvField(string field)
        {
            if (field.Contains("\""))
            {
                field = field.Replace("\"", "\"\"");
            }
            return field;
        }
    }

    public class ExportRequest
    {
        public string OverallStatus { get; set; }
        public string WaveNumber { get; set; }
        public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedDevices { get; set; }
        public List<DeviceData> FilteredData { get; set; }
        public List<DeviceData> PaginatedData { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeviceData
    {
        public string DeviceSerial { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string UserEmail { get; set; }
        public string LastUpdatedTime { get; set; }
        public string WaveRingNumber { get; set; }
        public string OverallStatus { get; set; }
    }
}

In the console, I'm getting output as:

But after getting saved, in Notepad, I see:

Also when opened the file in Excel, I see this:

And after that it shows corrupted message.
Any help will be thankful as wanted it to handle large data.
Thank you
